# How to call generic function from list of objects

Tags: c#, generics, pattern-matching

I have a generic list of objects, but the types within the list are all different types.  However, when iterating over the list of objects, and then calling a generic function, the type of T defined in the generic is of type Object.  How can I get the pattern matching to work so that type of T matches the concrete type of the object being validated?  For example, In the contrived example below, when calling Validate on the ValidationService, the line

```
  if(validator is IValidator<T> typedValidator)
```

always fails because type of T is object, and the physical implementation would be `IValidator<Widget>` or `IValidator<Entity>`.  How should I change the `DemonstrateProblem()` method so that the call to `validationService.Validate` uses the concrete type for the function and not the type of the type as defined in the the `List<object>`?  To make it slightly more complex, my actual code is also asynchronous, so I actually need a return value of `Task<IValidationResult<T>>`

```
namespace Contrived
{
    public interface IValidator { }
    public interface IValidationResult<T> { }
    public interface IValidator<T> : IValidator
    {
        IValidationResult<T> Validate(T entity);
    }

    public class ValidationResult<T> : IValidationResult<T>
    {
       public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class EntityValidator : Contrived.IValidator<Entity>
    {
        public IValidationResult<Entity> Validate(Entity entity)
        {
            return new ValidationResult<Entity>() { IsValid = true };
        }
    }

    public class Widget
    {
        public Guid UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }
    }

    public class WidgetValidator : IValidator<Widget>
    {
        public IValidationResult<Widget> Validate(Widget entity)
        {
            return new ValidationResult<Widget>() { IsValid = true };
        }
    }

    public class ValidationService
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, IValidator> validators;

        public ValidationService(Dictionary<Type, IValidator> validators)
        {
            this.validators = validators;
        }
        public IValidationResult<T> Validate<T>(T validatingObject)
        {
            var validator = validators[validatingObject.GetType()];
            if (validator is IValidator<T> typedValidator)
            {
                return typedValidator.Validate(validatingObject);
            }
            else throw new UnknownValidationType($"No known validator for type of {validatingObject.GetType()}");
        }
    }

    public class ServiceUser
    {
        private readonly ValidationService validationService;

        public ServiceUser(ValidationService validationService)
        {
            this.validationService = validationService;
        }

        public void DemonstrateProblem()
        {
            Widget widget = new Widget() { UniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid() };
            Entity entity = new Entity() { Id = 1, SomeProperty = "You know" };

            List<object> ObjectsToBeValidated = new List<object>() { widget, entity };
            foreach(var t in ObjectsToBeValidated)
            {
                validationService.Validate(t);//The Generic type of T is Object because that is the type of the List.  
                //How to get to be the concrete type of Widget and Entity?
            }
        }
    }

    public class UnknownValidationType : Exception {
        public UnknownValidationType(string message) : base(message)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sample code does not compile. Can you fix it to make life easier for anyone trying to answer the question?

Comment: Sure.  I only mocked the actual code to more clearly demonstrate the problem as opposed to be a runnable solution.  That said, I've updated the code.